# Browser Window 'maximize' event is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have been working with electron.js to build a custom title bar with basic buttons (minimize, restore/maximize, close). The problem comes when I am trying to add a 'maximize' event trigger onto the browser window. When I click on maximize button, it does not trigger the 'maximize' event. Also, try to click on maximize button and then on the minimize button, you can see that the 'maximize' trigger is invoked twice which is not expected.

I am trying to change the icon of the 'maximize' button when the window is maximized.

#### **main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow,ipcMain} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const ipc = ipcMain;


function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    minHeight:600,
    minWidth: 800,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame:false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      devTools:true,
      contextIsolation:false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  mainWindow.loadFile("src/index.html");
  // mainWindow.openDevTools();


  //From appFunction.js
  ipc.on('closeApp',()=>{
    mainWindow.close();
  });

  ipc.on('minimizeApp',()=>{
    mainWindow.minimize();
  });

  ipc.on('maximizeRestoreApp',()=>{
    if(mainWindow.isMaximized())
      mainWindow.restore();
    else
      mainWindow.maximize();
  });

  //BrowserWindow Events
  mainWindow.on('maximize',()=>{
    console.log("Window Maximized");
    mainWindow.webContents.send('isMaximized');
  });
  
  mainWindow.on('unmaximize',()=>{
    console.log("Window Restored");
    mainWindow.webContents.send('isRestored');
  });


}


app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})


app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Techie App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <script defer src = 'js/appFunctions.js'></script>
</head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainApp">
        <div class="topBar">
            <div class="titleBar">
                <button class="toggleButton" id="showHideMenus"></button>
                <img src="icons/logowhite.png" alt="Sample App">
                <div class="title">
                    Sample App
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="titleBarBtns">
                <button id="minimizeBtn" class="topBtn minimizeBtn" title="Minimize"></button>
                <button id="maxResBtn" class="topBtn maximizeBtn" title="Maximize"></button>
                <button id="closeBtn" class="topBtn closeBtn" title="Close"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contentArea">
            
            <div id="myLeftSideBar" class="leftSideBar">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### style.scss

```
html,body{
    background-color:#242526;
    margin: 0;
    min-height:100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#949AA7;
}

.mainApp{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #343b48;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    .topBar{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color:#1B1D23;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #1B1D23;
        -webkit-user-select: none;

        .titleBar{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction:row;
            align-items:center;
            width: 100%;
            .toggleButton{
                width:45px;
                height: 40px;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                background-color:transparent;
                background-image: url(../icons/menu.svg);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center;
                transition: 0.2s;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .toggleButton:hover{
                background-color: #272C36;
            }

            .toggleButton:active{
                background-color: #4F9FEE;
            }

            img{
                margin-left: 10px;
                height: 32px;
            }

            .title{
                margin-left: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                line-height: 30px;
                margin-top: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
                -webkit-app-region:drag;
            }
        }

        .titleBarBtns{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            width: 120px;
            height: 40px;

            .topBtn{
                width: 40px;
                height:40px;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                background-color: transparent;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center;
                transition: 0.2s;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .topBtn:hover{
                background-color: #272c36;
            }
            .topBtn:active{
                background-color: #4F9FEE;
            }
            .minimizeBtn{
                background-image: url(../icons/minimize.png);
            }
            .maximizeBtn{
                background-image: url(../icons/maximize.png);
            }

            .closeBtn{
                background-image: url(../icons/close.png);
            }

            .restoreBtn{
                background-image: url(../icons/minimize.png);
            }

        }
    } 
    

    .contentArea{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        .leftSideBar{
            width:280px;
            height:100%;
            background-color: #272C36;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }
    }
}
```

#### appFunction.js

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
const ipc = ipcRenderer;

const maxResBtn = document.getElementById('maxResBtn');
const closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn');
const minimizeBtn = document.getElementById('minimizeBtn');

closeBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    console.log('closeBtn Pressed');
    ipc.send('closeApp');
});


minimizeBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    console.log('minimizeBtn Pressed');
    ipc.send('minimizeApp');
});


maxResBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    console.log('maximizeRestoreBtn Pressed');
    ipc.send('maximizeRestoreApp');
});

function changeMaxResBtn(isMaximizedApp){
    if(isMaximizedApp){
        maxResBtn.title = 'Restore';
        maxResBtn.classList.remove('maximizeBtn');
        maxResBtn.classList.add('restoreBtn');
    }else{
        maxResBtn.title = 'Maximize';
        maxResBtn.classList.remove('restoreBtn');
        maxResBtn.classList.add('maximizeBtn');
    }
}

ipc.on('isMaximized',()=>{changeMaxResBtn(true)});
ipc.on('isRestored',()=>{changeMaxResBtn(false)});
```

Comment: `you can see that the 'maximize' trigger is invoked twice` - no, we can't see that actually

Comment: Is it working fine for you?

Comment: is what working? do you think I copied your code, figured out your folder hierarchy, and put it on my server to test it?  hint: no, I did not do those things, so how can I "see that"